# Join-like operation and Medvedev reducibility

Tags: computability-theory

Let $\mathcal C, \mathcal D\subseteq 2^\omega$.
Let
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Either}{Either}
    \Either(\mathcal C,\mathcal D)=\{A\oplus B: \text{either }A\in \mathcal C, B\in\mathcal D\text{, or }B\in \mathcal C, A\in\mathcal D\}
$$
Has this operation been named and studied in the context of Medvedev degrees (i.e., strong reducibility of mass problems)?

Its interest comes from the fact that from an element of $\Either(\mathcal C,\mathcal D)$ we cannot necessarily compute an element of $\mathcal C$ (or $\mathcal D$) uniformly.

Comment: Note that this isn't Medvedev-degree-invariant: if every element of $\mathcal{C}$ begins with $0$ and every element of $\mathcal{D}$ begins with $1$ then $\mathsf{Either}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ is just their join, and every mass problem is Medvedev-equivalent to one with a "common first bit."

Comment: @NoahSchweber right. I've edited the title accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kojiro Higuchi and Takayuki Kihara have studied operations of this flavour in their papers "Inside the Muchnik degrees" I+II ([doi Part 1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2014.01.003),[doi Part 2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2014.03.001)). It has been a few years since I read those, and I do not remember whether this particular operation plays a role. However, the idea of combining sets in ways that foil uniform reductions features very heavily in this work.

Comment: Fantastic thanks @Arno

Comment: Lemma 4 of the 2nd paper concerns a closely related operation.